# Historical Data Resample Issue

Tags: python, pandas

My historical data (`PLUS.L`) starts from `24/07/2013` to `01/08/2019` and my code below changed from daily to monthly but I get result from `31/01/2013` to `31/12/2019` when I should get result from `31/07/2013` to `31/08/2019`.  Have I overlooked something?  By the way, I am using Python 3.7.4

Here is my result Date 
2013-01-31 0.807268 
2013-02-28 0.886933 
2013-03-31 0.963781 
2013-04-30 0.967294 
2013-05-31 0.968885 ... 
2019-08-31 9.309789 
2019-09-30 8.204365 
2019-10-31 7.734376 
2019-11-30 9.369938 
2019-12-31 7.178695 
Freq: M, Name: Adj Close, Length: 84, dtype: float64

Here is my snippet code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("PLUS.L.csv", index_col=0)
df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index)
result = df.resample('M')['Adj Close'].mean()
```

Comment: Edit the question and add this result to it. Also as "pandas" tag

Comment: can you try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184181/resample-daily-data-to-get-monthly-dataframe#answer-52185636